# MYSQL Php parsing error

Tags: php

I am unable to figure out the parsing error on this piece of code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"http://online.somewebsite.com/" . $info['path'] . >" . $info['value'] . "</a>";
            echo "</li>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<li><a href="http://online.saomewebsite.com/' . $info['path'] .'">' . $info['value'] . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: This does not append the path after somewebsite.com/.
Thanks!

Comment: you might take a look at the modification. I only moved the quotation to the other side of `$info['path']`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. And also made me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You forget " before > in second line

```
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"http://online.saomewebsite.com/" . $info['path'] . ">" . $info['value'] . "</a>";
echo "</li>";
```

Comment: This does not work, it messes up the link to look something like this in the address bar
http://online.saomewebsite.com/value </a></li><li><a href=

Comment: ok, I see an error. Try this: `echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"http://online.saomewebsite.com/" . $info['path'] . "\">" . $info['value'] . "</a>";
echo "</li>";`